# How to Access Local tiles in Android Phone

Tags: android, openlayers, openlayers-3

we are building a hybrid app and working on adding offline tile loading functionality. How we can access local tiles in mobile device. We are planning to load local tiles from SD card.Open layer SRC needs the serve address .

Is open layer 3 is having `OL.Control.CacheWrite` like open layer 2, and if it is not available now, by when we expect to available in open layer 3?

Answer (score 0):

This works reading local tiles in my desktop, I guess it should work in a mobile app too:

```
var MBLayer =  new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: './POSOW_layer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            zIndex:9999999
          })
        });
```

being 'POSOW_layer' the name of the directory where the tiles are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, We tried this solution but it worked only when we hosted the app in IIS server. Coming to the Mobile app we cannot run in any server in mobile so instead of taking a server like path it takes path like "file://posow_layer" which doesn't work in mobile app.